# Книги по программированию на С++ под Win

Tags: c++, книги

Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, книги по программированию по программированию на С++ под Win.
 Изучаю С++ уже некоторое время, хочется поизучать что-то более близкое к "реальным" программам, чем консольные приложения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/) уже не в почете?
ИМХО: сейчас то и книг именно "С++ под Win" нет, потому что MSDN хватает выше крыши.

Остальное уже чисто c++ и трюки :)

Comment: MSDN более чем в почете, но интересует именно учебник, где на первый раз все разложат по полочкам, и чтобы он был на русском языке.  
Читаю Литвиненко Н.А.-Технология программирования на С++. Win32 API-приложения-2010

Comment: На русском: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ff976566.aspx

Вместо книг "MSDN Библиотека": http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/default.aspx
там есть исходные коды реальных программ и пояснения к ним.

Книги на русском по рекомендации самой Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/gg601080.aspx

Comment: Что-то я в книгах вижу только одну, Сидорина Т. MFC и MS Visual Studio C++. Разработка приложений, но все равно спасибо.